# short-circuit operators

Tags: c#

I started learning C#, when reading the Logical Operators, I found that:

The || operator represents a logical operator and expression 2 is not evaluated if expression 1 is TRUE. I'm curious about this example:

```
int x = 5, y = 10;
bool result;

result = (x == 3) || (y != 5);
label12.Text = result.ToString();
```

If we already know that the value of X is 5, then how the result (x==3) could return true?? Because the left hand side operator in this case returns TRUE. But how?? X =5 and It should be X ==5??? What I misunderstood?? Can someone explain me in a few words??

Much appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: As you said; _expression 2 is not evaluated if expression 1 is TRUE_ In your case, _expression 1_ is `false` and _expression 2_ is evaluated. `result = false || true` and `result` will be `true`.

Comment: It will evaluate both conditions in this case.

Comment: `result` will be `true` because `(y != 5)` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: In your example, expression 2 will be evaluated because x does not equal 5.

Comment: `false || true` is `true`

Comment: OMG, I thought  have to pay attention only to the first one . Very clear now! Thanks!

Comment: @user2648071 if the operator is `&&`, both the left and right expressions must be true in order to return true.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: The `||` operator is not an _exclusive_ or (i.e. only one of the conditions can be true), which is a common misconception when starting to learn a language such as C#. If _any_ of the conditions are `true` in a chain of `||` operations, then the result is `true`.

Comment: @avanek: That certainly isn't the confusion taking place here.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: That's why it's a comment. It's a corollary to the original question. I've taught people programming basics before and that was a common pitfall when they were getting their head around Boolean logic.

Comment: Thanks guys for commenting, when I read this line "The || operator represents a logical operator and expression 2 is not evaluated if expression 1 is TRUE. " I just thought the game should finish there, seems got my mind tired after reading the book during without having a coffee break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short circuit evaluation means that the compiler stops to evaluate the expression immediately when it could determine the result ot the whole expression

In your case, when the compiler finds the expression `x==3` to be false it cannot stop the evaluation because the second part of the expression could be true.

So it is forced to continue the evaluation, it finds the expression `y != 5` to be true and the whole expression become FALSE || TRUE

[See the C# reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6373h346%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Short circuit operations means that here

```
result = (x == 3) || (y != 5);
```

`y != 5` part would not be evaluated if `x == 3` is already true. Basically because there is no need for this - we already know that whole expression is true.

If x is 5 however, both expression will be evaluated, because we still do not know whole result after `x == 3`.

**Update.** Maybe the purpose of this would be more clear with this example. Conside the following, of course simplified, code:

```
var someObj = SomeOperation();
if (someObj != null && someObj.IsActive)
```

What would happen if `SomeOperation()` returned null? If it wasn't for short-circuit evaluation of this logical statement, this code will throw `NullReferenceException`. However `IsActive` call will not be called if `someObj` is null.

Answer (score 1):

It's an or. The left hand side is false, so it evaluates the right hand side, which is true.

Answer (score 1):

Lets break it down...

```
    int x = 5, y = 10;
    result = (x == 3) || (y != 5);
```

`(x==3)` is false
`(y!=5)` is true

Since you used **`||`** the first part of the conditional `(x==3)` is false so we need to continue evaluating any other conditionals to determine if the overall expression is true or false ... if the first expression were true we could stop there because the entire expression wouldn't change with continued evaluation and the second part of the conditional would be "short-circuited".

In this case the `(y!=5)` must be evaluated which returns true and makes the rest of the expression true.

If instead you used **`&&`** to combine your conditionals then if either side is false the entire expression is false.

```
int x = 5, y = 10;
result = (x == 3) && (y != 5);
```

Since in this case `(x==3)` is false, no other evaluation needs to be done and result would be set to false without evaluating `(y!=5)`

Answer (score 0):

(x == 3) should not evaluate to True. (x ==3) evaluates to False, so (y != 5) gets evaluated and that is true. That is why result is True.